# WCF - Cannot have child contents to be deserialized as an object problem

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I working on wcf with object service parameters, like this;

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace="http://mydomain")]
public interface IBasicService 
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "TestPost", Method = "POST", 
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest)]
    object TestPost(object request);
}

[DataContract]
public class RequestModelA 
{
.
.
.
}

[DataContract]
public class RequestModelB
{
.
.
.
}
```

I want to consume this service, with more than one request body type like RequestModelA, RequestModelB and response type ResponseA, ResponseB.

When I call the service this request:

```
<soapenv:Envelope
    xmlns:soapenv=....>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <ser:TestPost>
            <ser:request>
                <PropertyA>Value</PropertyA>
            </ser:request>
        </ser:TestPost>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelop>
```

Return this error.

> The formatter threw an
> exception while trying to deserialize the message: There was an error
> while trying to deserialize parameter ...:request. The InnerException
> message was 'Element request from ... cannot have child contents to be
> deserialized as an object. Please use XmlNode[] to deserialize this
> pattern of XML.

How can I call wcf service with object parameter or generate web service working generic types?

Comment: You can try to add the [DataMember] on the class RequestModelA and RequestModelB.

Comment: [DataMember] attribute is exist on properties. But I didn't write to this question.

Comment: There are two ways to try this : 1.Use THE XML format, define your own rules, and parse according to the rules. 2.Compress and then decompress or pass the binary.